# What did Stefan Zweig mean when he said "becoming old is no longer being afraid of the past"?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, german-language, stefan-zweig

In *24 hours in the life of a woman*, Stefan Zweig writes "becoming old is no longer being afraid of the past". What did he mean by this?

Comment: Perhaps you might tell us what you think it means. It seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: @Lambie Pretty straightforward and yet requiring a whole life of wisdom before you can truly get it!!